# Live template auto completion priority

Tags: css, phpstorm, webstorm

How can I change the priority for different auto completion options in CSS/LESS files?

Example:
When I quickly enter "dib" followed by tab, that should be converted to "display: inline-block;" as configured in the CSS Live Template settings.
But unfortunately, PhpStorm decided it would make more sense to convert the shortcut to "drop-initial-before-adjust" instead... (see attached screenshot)

Is there a way to change this behavior?

[image: PhpStorm CSS auto completion screenshot]

Comment: I've not used LESS and CSS Live templates but isn't the shortcut for display:inline-block; just d:ib and not dib? Sorry if I'm not helping

Comment: It is, but PhpStorm always does a first-letter-search. That's why "dib" matches both "d:ib" and "drop-initial-before-adjust". (Yes, I can circumvent the problem by typing "d:ib" instead of "dib", but I'm working with German keyboard layout, so it is a lot quicker to type "dib" instead of "d:ib".)

Comment: What about: 1) changing `d:ib` to `dib` and then do not use automatic code completion popup -- this way you can type `dib[TAB]` and it will be expanded to your live template .. or use `Ctrl+Space` instead of `TAB` to get code completion popup and complete that CSS3 property? Regarding changing priority in such case: there is no such explicit options for that (unless you disable fussy Emmet search -- *maybe* it will provide better ordering).

Comment: Yes, I could change all the Live Templates that include a ":", but those are a lot... Another thing is, in a previous version of PhpStorm, it worked exactly like I wanted... so it must have been changed with an update (or I messed with some settings and just don't remember it now ;)).  (EDIT: This has nothing to do with Emmet, I have disabled it anyway.)

Comment: Sorry I was wrong there. Enabling fuzzy css search in Emmet settings actually does exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling "Fuzzy search among css abbreviations" in the Emmet settings does exactly what I wanted.